# Extracting an archive with millions of files with 7z is very slow

Tags: windows-7, 7-zip

I have an archive with ~2 millions files, each of them being a few KB when uncompressed. The extraction is extremely slow (1 or 2 files per second). I see that 7z uses 100% of one CPU core.  Is it expected that 7z takes so much CPU? Does 7z have issues handling archives containing millions of files?

The extraction is fast for approximately the first million of files, then drastically slows down.

My configuration is fairly typical and I believe should allow a faster extraction:

- Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate
- MSI GE70 0ND-033US (Intel® Core™ i7-3610QM Processor, 16 GB of RAM, no swap)
- Crucial M500 SSD
- 7z version 9.22 beta
- the archive was created on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 LTS with `zip -r pubmed01-02.zip pubmed`
- partitions are NTFS

[image]

7z benchmark:

[image]

Comment: The benchmark indicates all 8 threads are being used, the speed, matches that performance.  So that means that clearly when your attempting to extract the files your using a single thread.  This is either a case of a bug or a case of a missing argument.  Of course 1 or 2 files a second indicates a larger problem, because that is several times magnitude smaller then it should be

Comment: Because either operation uses a temp , how about the Options-Folder-location, nice speedy spot for that?  Plus possibility to uncheck the "for removable only" so you can target a hardware different drive for that particual I/O (or ram disk even)?  (as opposed to a different partition, which would be on the same disk

Comment: You don't mention how much system memory you have.  I mean you do have a 11 GB archive, which means all that data, will eventually find it into memory.  Update question so that reason can be eliminated.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, I have fixed the benchmark screenshot to only 1 CPU, and added how much system memory I have (the system has no swap). 7z takes less than 20 MB when decompressing.

Comment: You have no swap that means the 7zip would be forced to load the entire file into memory.  I suspect thats part of your problem.  You can't increase the dictionary size to something larger perhaps 25-50% of your system memory?

Comment: @Ramhound Why no swap means the 7zip would be forced to load the entire file into memory? Can't it read the archive sequentially? Also, looking at the Task Manager, 7z takes less than 20 MB when decompressing.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - It could read it  sequentially if you enabled a swap.